# Proof for the behavior of both types of improper integrals for different powers of x

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, exponentiation

I was trying to prove for what values of p **eq.1** converges or diverges, they didn't give the proof for **eq.1** but for **eq.2** a proof was given and when I was done with the proof for **eq.1** I noticed that for the second one they specified from which-side they approached zero (see **eq.4**) but I didn't specify from which side I approached infinity (see **eq.3**). I didn't do that because without graphing I usually can't tell which side to use and this is general and not a specific exercise or example, anyways, could proof **eq.3** be considered incomplete if I don't specify from which side I approached infinity?

[image]

Comment: In 3), $b$ is a (varying) real number. So it can only "approach $\infty$" from below. There is therefore no need to specify.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, for **eq.1**, we see that, by the fundamental theorem of calculus, that $$\int_a^{\infty}x^{-p}dx=\lim_{c\to\infty}\frac{c^{-p+1}}{(-p+1)}-\frac{a^{-p+1}}{(-p+1)}$$Except the special case $p=1$, we have $\lim_{c\to \infty}\ln(c)-\ln(a)$, which diverges.

But for most values of $p$, this will diverge based on $$\lim_{c\to\infty}c^{-p+1}=\pm\infty?$$

It hangs on whether or not $p\le1$.  In those cases, it will diverge.

For **eq. 2**, we use the same method:$$\int_0^ax^{-p}dx=\frac{0^{-p+1}}{(-p+1)}-\frac{a^{-p+1}}{(-p+1)}$$What determines if this diverges is based on $$0^{-p+1}$$If $p\le1$, then this is undefined and the integral will diverge.

For **eq.3** and **4**, I cannot help you.

Comment: This I already knew, but it was a question about right and left side limits. But thank you.

Comment: Shrugs.  I've barely learned calculus, sorry.